# How can I change the default indentation based on filetype?

Tags: indentation, filetype

I'd like to have different indentations based on the type of file I am working on. For example, working on a `.c` file I'd like my indentation be 4 spaces. In `.html` files I'd like to (have to) work with tabs.

How do I achieve that?

Comment: In case you would like to disable auto-indention for LaTeX, use `autocmd FileType plaintex,tex,context setlocal indentexpr=`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The best method is to put those settings in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/<filetype>.vim`.

For HTML (assuming you want 4 characters-wide tabs):

```
~/.vim/after/ftplugin/html.vim

setlocal shiftwidth=4
setlocal softtabstop=4
setlocal noexpandtab
```

Using an ftplugin is prefered to using autocommands because Vim already does filetype checks by itself and already tries to source the adequate ftplugin so there's no reason to force even more checks and reimplement the wheel.

-- edit --

Assuming you have `filetype plugin on` in your `vimrc` — which you should — Vim will try to detect the filetype of the files you edit and, once the correct filetype is found and set for the buffer, try to source the corresponding ftplugin in these standard locations:

```
$VIMRUNTIME/ftplugin/html.vim
~/.vim/ftplugin/html.vim
~/.vim/ftplugin/after/html.vim
```

All of that happens *automatically* so, if your filetype is recognized by Vim, there is absolutely no reason to add any filetype detection logic: just add your settings to the right ftplugin and you are good.

Comment: Do I need to activate the ftplugin somehow or will creating the file(s) activate it automatically?

Comment: Make sure you have `filetype plugin indent on` in your `vimrc`.

Comment: @DeltaLima vim has a path that it goes through to check for settings. As long as `filetype plugin on` is set, vim's path includes the `ftplugin/<filetype>.vim` and `after/ftplugin/<filetype>/vim` files in its path.

Comment: @DeltaLima, please see my edit.

Comment: Setting `softtabstop` and `shiftwidth` will use a mix of tabs and spaces. You're usually better off using `tabstop`.

Answer (score 14):

You can do this with autocommands in your `.vimrc`.

For example, I have a function `html_like_mode` that sets up various things for editing HTML files. In my `.vimrc`, I have:

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.html call s:html_like_mode()
```

That keys off of the file extension. You can also key off of the filetype, if you have that enabled:

```
au FileType perl setlocal equalprg=perltidy
```

As you can see, you can have it do any command there. So you could easily do a `setlocal shiftwidth 4` for your *.c files.

Answer (score 12):

`augroup` allows you to group related autocommands into named groups. (See [here](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/14.html) to learn about Autocommand Groups.) We use `augroup`s to add autocommands to `~/.vimrc` in a way that won't add a duplicate every time we source it.

```
augroup vimrc
  autocmd!
augroup END

autocmd vimrc FileType html setlocal shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4
```

Comment: It would be useful if you would explain what this does and how to set it up, not everyone will know ;)

Answer (score 8):

Used **autocmd** and **FileType**

```
autocmd FileType html setlocal shiftwidth=4 tabstop=4
```