# How can I stop vim automatically inserting a tab in CSS files?

Tags: indentation

When I am in a CSS file with a blank line, like this:

[image]

and I want to simply make a new line and move down to it, by hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> , vim is auto inserting a tab character, e.g.

[image]

Running `:set fo?` inside the CSS file => `formatoptions=croql`.
If I disable all formatoptions with `:set fo=` - it still happens.
however if format options are disabled using `:set paste` vim does stop inserting the tab - but I dont want to have to work in paste mode all the time!

settings:

- `noautoindent`
- `nosmartindent`
- `nocindent`

If I turn off filetype specific indenting with

```
filetype indent off
```

It still happens, what am I missing - do I need to restart vim or something for the settings to take effect?

How can I stop vim autoinserting these tab characters?

Comment: Try if setting `:setlocal expandtab` helps

Answer (score 13):

I found a couple of ways to solve the problem.

#### 1. reload the buffer after running `:filetype indent off`

Vim's docs (`:help :filetype-indent-off`)  provided an explanation:

> You can disable `:filetype indent on` with:
>
> ```
> :filetype indent off
> ```
>
> This actually loads the file "indoff.vim" in 'runtimepath'.
>   This disables auto-indenting for files you will open.  It will keep working in
>   already opened files.  Reset 'autoindent', 'cindent', 'smartindent' and/or
>   'indentexpr' to disable indenting in an opened file.

- *"It will keep working in already opened files."* - explained that I simply had to kill and reload the buffer after I ran the command `:filetype indent off`

#### 2. Reset indentexpr

per docs

> Reset 'autoindent', 'cindent', 'smartindent' and/or
>   'indentexpr' to disable indenting in an opened file.

it turned out the issue was caused by `indentexpr` which had the value of

```
indentexpr=GetCSSIndent()
Last set from /usr/share/vim/vim74/indent/css.vim
```

I was able to reset it with: `:set indentexpr=""`

which also fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has already been answered, but I though I could also add my solution:

As suggested by filbranden, it's better to not modified `vim`'s system files. Instead, he suggested to use `skip_defaults_vim=1` or create a `.vimrc` file in my home directory to disable the default features. If I want any of the default features, I can add them to my `.vimrc` file.

In my case (vim 8.1), disabling the defaults does the trick. I like vim highlight feature, but that feature is defined elsewhere so disabling the defaults do not disable highlighting.

I added the following line at the beginning of `/etc/vim/vimrc`:

```
let skip_defaults_vim=1
```

----------- Old answer (not recommended) -----------

If you simply want to disable auto-indent system wise, for every file type (basically, disable the auto-indent feature completely), you can do the following:

1. Backup the `indent.vim` file:
   `sudo mv /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent.vim /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent.vim.orig`
2. Create a new empty `indent.vim` file:
   `sudo touch /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent.vim`

**IMPORTANT NOTE**: Modifying system files is **not recommended**. It can have unexpected side effect. Also, the modification is likely to be overwritten on the next vim update. Avoid this solution if possible.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! This will break as soon as you upgrade the Vim package in your system, which will overwrite this file back to its original contents... The `indent.vim` file is being loaded by the file type detection code, and you can disable indent support easily by adding `filetype indent off` to your vimrc file instead, that's a much better approach.

Comment: Thanks filbranden. I wish that approach would work, that would be much cleaner. Unfortunately, at least on Ubuntu, adding `filetype indent off` at the end (or even at the beginning of the file) of `/etc/vim/vimrc` has no effect.

Comment: That's because `filetype plugin indent on` will be executed by `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` which is run if the user has no `.vimrc` in their home directory, and it runs after the system-wide vimrc. You should really use a user vimrc file and not the system one... If you want to disable the `defaults.vim` file, you can use `let skip_defaults_vim = 1` in your system vimrc file (but note that `defaults.vim` sets up a lot of other useful stuff, such as syntax highlighting.) See [`:help defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim) for details.

Comment: I have restored the `/usr/share/vim/vim81/indent.vim` file and verified that the auto-indent was back. Then I `touch ~/.vimrc` to create an empty `.vimrc` file. The auto-indent is gone! Thanks.

NOTE: I tried this earlier (a few version of vim back, when I was running Debian). After creating an empty `.vimrc` in my home directory, I would lose a lot of features, such as highlighting which I like. I will edit my answer.

Comment: For years this automatic indention features harassing me. Now I can stop this 'feature'. Thank you. This is best answer. Any other anwsers can't help much.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option, first find your file type by typing `:set filetype?` within your Vim opened file.
Suppose it spits out `css`, then in your `.vimrc` file, add the line

```
autocmd FileType css setlocal indentexpr=
```

Comment: Consider using ftplugins (`~/.vim/after/ftplugin/css.vim`) rather than autocommands.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks for the comment, could you clarify why it is preferable to use plugins? I tend to solve everything within `.vimrc` file because that way I have only one file to keep track of.

Comment: It’s reinventing the wheel, and may be slower. Vim already has a Filetype autocommand that will trigger all the ftplugin scripts. Adding more autocommands gives it more to do when it already has a mechanism for that. Besides, your vimrc can live in your .vim directory, so then you only have one directory to keep track of. I also find that its more organized and that it makes complex configurations easier, since the autocommand syntax can get a bit clumsy.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks for the explanation, however when you get a new laptop, you would have to remember to copy all the `ftplugin` scripts. Is there a way to automate?

Comment: Copy the single directory `~/.vim`; that’s where all the configuration is. In fact you could version control this directory, or all of your dotfiles. I do this, along with a makefile (sort of) to create symlinks and install things.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Thanks, it is a nice option!

Answer (score -1):

Yes this solved for me also this unkind effect:

I opened, and edited my ~/.vimrc

```
:filetype indent off
```

If you do not like the higlight scheme, you just search the selected colorscheme here:

```
/usr/share/vim/vim74/colors
```

i use generaly "colorscheme desert", in the 77-th row you find:

```
  hi Search cterm=NONE ctermfg=grey ctermbg=lightblue
  hi Search cterm=bold ctermfg=black ctermbg=green
```

that was for me better than the lightbue

Comment: This answer is incorrect. See https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/4175 for an example of vimrc syntax (IOW, you cannot use `:` syntax inside ~/.vimrc).