# How to disable bad indentation when pasting text?

Tags: indentation, cut-copy-paste

I am using vim and simply want to disable auto indent when I paste text into my terminal vim session. I have tried numerous solutions including various incantations of below to `~/.vimrc`:

```
set nopaste

"  https://kb.iu.edu/d/afcw
"  set noautoindent


"   https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5310/how-can-i-stop-vim-automatically-inserting-a-tab-in-css-files
"  set indentexpr=""


filetype indent off


"  set pastetoggle=
set pastetoggle=

" set paste


" se paste


" au FileType html,htmldjango setlocal indentexpr=


" set nosmartindent
" set cindent
" filetype plugin indent on
" set cinkeys-=0#
" set indentkeys-=0#
" autocmd FileType * set cindent "some file types override it


"  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106526/stop-vim-from-messing-up-my-indentation-on-comments
set nosmartindent
set cindent
set cinkeys-=0#
set indentkeys-=0#
```

As you can see bad advice is easily obtained. I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and have not customized anything so its stock vim. I see the vim package has given me

```
~/.vim/bundle/Vundle.vim/
```

which I have not modified

```
vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Nov 24 2016 16:44:48)
Included patches: 1-1689
Extra patches: 8.0.0056
Modified by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Compiled by pkg-vim-maintainers@lists.alioth.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
```

Here is an example of badness when I paste properly formatted code into vim  `vim blah.go`

```
import (
            "bufio"
                "fmt"
                    "os"
                        "bytes"
                            "io"
                    )

                    func read_stdin(io_reader io.Reader) (string, error) {

                                var buffer bytes.Buffer

                                    scanner := bufio.NewScanner( io_reader )

                                        for scanner.Scan() {
                                                        buffer.WriteString( scanner.Text() + "\n" )
                                                            }
                                                                if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {

                                                                                return "", err
                                                                                    }
```

This auto indent issue pervades many filename suffixes so I am not looking for any suffix specific or source code editing language specific addons.

PS this was never an issue until about a year ago

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for [`:h 'paste'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27paste%27) and [`:h 'pastetoggle'`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/options.txt.html#%27pastetoggle%27).

It is not really a good idea to set `paste` in your vimrc since most of the time you don't want to have it set.

The idea is to use `set paste` just before you copy your text and go back to `nopaste` right after.

The easiest way to do that is to put something like this in your `vimrc`:

```
set pastetoggle=<F11>
```

Then you can simply press `<F11>` before and after you paste and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

I find its easier to put below into top of my ~/.vimrc

```
unlet! skip_defaults_vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim

"  to shut off paste indent
se paste
```

this is on Ubuntu 18.04 and above when using stock vim

here are vim version details

```
/usr/bin/vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 15 2020 06:40:31)
Included patches: 1-2269
Modified by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Compiled by team+vim@tracker.debian.org
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               -farsi             -mouse_sysmouse    -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_xterm       +termguicolors
+autochdir         +float             +multi_byte        +terminal
-autoservername    +folding           +multi_lang        +terminfo
-balloon_eval      -footer            -mzscheme          +termresponse
+balloon_eval_term +fork()            +netbeans_intg     +textobjects
-browse            +gettext           +num64             +textprop
++builtin_terms    -hangul_input      +packages          +timers
+byte_offset       +iconv             +path_extra        +title
+channel           +insert_expand     -perl              -toolbar
+cindent           +job               +persistent_undo   +user_commands
-clientserver      +jumplist          +postscript        +vartabs
-clipboard         +keymap            +printer           +vertsplit
+cmdline_compl     +lambda            +profile           +virtualedit
+cmdline_hist      +langmap           -python            +visual
+cmdline_info      +libcall           +python3           +visualextra
+comments          +linebreak         +quickfix          +viminfo
+conceal           +lispindent        +reltime           +vreplace
+cryptv            +listcmds          +rightleft         +wildignore
+cscope            +localmap          -ruby              +wildmenu
+cursorbind        -lua               +scrollbind        +windows
+cursorshape       +menu              +signs             +writebackup
+dialog_con        +mksession         +smartindent       -X11
+diff              +modify_fname      +sound             -xfontset
+digraphs          +mouse             +spell             -xim
-dnd               -mouseshape        +startuptime       -xpm
-ebcdic            +mouse_dec         +statusline        -xsmp
+emacs_tags        +mouse_gpm         -sun_workshop      -xterm_clipboard
+eval              -mouse_jsbterm     +syntax            -xterm_save
+ex_extra          +mouse_netterm     +tag_binary        
+extra_search      +mouse_sgr         -tag_old_static    
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
Compilation: gcc -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -Wdate-time  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/vim-iU6mZD/vim-8.1.2269=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_REENTRANT -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1       
Linking: gcc   -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -Wl,--as-needed -o vim        -lm -ltinfo -lnsl  -lselinux  -lcanberra -lacl -lattr -lgpm -ldl     -L/usr/lib/python3.8/config-3.8-x86_64-linux-gnu -lpython3.8 -lcrypt -lpthread -ldl -lutil -lm -lm
```