# How to apply certain vim config only to .py files

Tags: vimscript

I have found the setting that are currently working for me for python development in vim.

```
"set tabs to have 4 spaces
set ts=4

" expand tabs into spaces
set expandtab

" enable all Python syntax highlighting features
let python_highlight_all = 1
```

The issue is, that these settings are getting in the way when opening other documents, for example Makefiles.

Is it possible to use these settings to apply only for `*.py` files?

Comment: Read `:h ftplugins`, `:h ftplugin`, and `:h vimfiles`.

Comment: I accidentally voted to close "because this is too broad".  I don't agree with the choice of duplicate questions.  This is the actual duplicate: [How can I change the default indentation based on filetype?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4/how-can-i-change-the-default-indentation-based-on-filetype)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for autocommands, something like this:

```
autocmd FileType python setlocal showmatch
```

Would set the `showmatch` option only on buffers with the python filetype.

See [`:h :autocmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#:autocmd).

```
" ###############################
" Settings I want for all files #
" ###############################


" enable syntax highlighting for all the languages vim recognizes by default
syntax enable

" indent when moving to the next line while writing code
set autoindent

" show the matching part of the pair for [] {} and ()
set showmatch

" ########################################
" Settings related to python development #
" ########################################


autocmd Filetype    python 
                \   setlocal ts=4 |
                \   setlocal expandtab 

" enable all Python syntax highlighting features
" it doesn't highlight issues on other files even 
" though it's not in autocmd. Don't know
let python_highlight_all = 1
```