# Why does vim still auto-indent LaTeX after I set noai noci nosi?

Tags: indentation, filetype-tex

I want to disable autoindent and smartindent for LaTeX so I did

```
:set noai noci nosi
```

When I open a brand new `mwe.tex`, `filetype=plaintex` and there is no auto indent magic.

When I then enter some code, such as `\begin{frame}\end{frame}`, save and reopen the file, `filetype=tex`, colours have changed, and... there is what to me looks like both auto indent and smart indent going on:

- I start typing `\begin{frame}` at the beginning of the line, so far so good
- I press enter, and the cursor is indented by four spaces, despite setting `noai`, `noci`, and `nosi`.  At this point, `:set` shows:

```
--- Options ---
  background=dark     helplang=en         shiftwidth=4        ttyfast
  commentstring=%%s nomodeline            showmatch           ttymouse=xterm
  expandtab           modified            suffixesadd=.tex
  filetype=tex        ruler               syntax=tex
  foldmethod=indent   scroll=34           tabstop=4
  backspace=indent,eol,start
  comments=sO:% -,mO:%  ,eO:%%,:%
  define=\\\([egx]\|char\|mathchar\|count\|dimen\|muskip\|skip\|toks\)\=def\|\\font\|\\\(future\)\
=let\|\\new\(count\|dimen\|skip\|muskip\|box\|toks\|read\|write\|fam\|insert\)\|\\\(re\)\=new\(boo
lean\|command\|counter\|environment\|font\|if\|length\|savebox\|theorem\(style\)\=\)\s*\*\=\s*{\=\
|DeclareMathOperator\s*{\=\s*
  fileencoding=utf-8
  fileencodings=ucs-bom,utf-8,default,latin1
  include=\\input\|\\include{
  includeexpr=substitute(v:fname, '^.\{-}{\|}.*', '', 'g')
  indentexpr=GetTeXIndent()
  indentkeys=0{,0},:,0#,!^F,o,O,e,[,(,{,),},],&,=\bibitem,=\item
```

- I type `\end{frame` at the indented base.  After I add a `}`, it gets automatically dedented (with a fraction of a second delay).

From `:scriptnames`, I can tell there are scripts loaded at `/usr/share/vim/vim80/indent.vim`,  `/usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/tex.vim`, `/usr/share/vim/vim80/ftplugin/tex.vim`, and `/usr/share/vim/vim80/indent/tex.vim`.  So it looks like there is a script overriding the standard vim settings.  How do I configure the behaviour of this script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`'indentexpr'` has the highest priority of how vim can automatically indent lines.

`:h 'indentexpr'`:

> When this option is not empty, it overrules the `'cindent'` and
>       `'smartindent'` indenting.

Your value is `indentexpr=GetTeXIndent()`.

**Customize `GetTeXIndent()`**

The behavior of `GetTeXIndent()` can be customized by a few variables (e.g. `g:tex_indent_brace` or `g:tex_indent_items`). They are documented in-source in [`$VIMRUNTIME/indent/tex.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/eb3dc87f01391bb075d97aef3d00f91b4e08a25c/runtime/indent/tex.vim#L70-L122).

If you only want to disable the indentation after `\begin{frame}` but keep indenting other code, you can put in your vimrc

```
let g:tex_noindent_env = 'document\|verbatim\|lstlisting\|frame'
```

This variable is also respected by `Tex_CalcIdent()` of [vim-latex](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex) and `BuckyTeXIndent()` of [vim-bucky](https://github.com/dbmrq/vim-bucky).

**Vimtex user: Customize `VimtexIndentExpr()`**

[vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex) provides its own indentation function `VimtexIndentExpr()`. This function can be customized with a similar option `g:vimtex_indent_ignored_envs` which, however, is a list of names

```
let g:vimtex_indent_ignored_envs = ['document', 'verbatim', 'lstlisting', 'frame']
```

**Disable indentation completely**

`:set indentexpr=`

**Permanent vim setting**

If you want to `set indentexpr=` permanently in your vim config, see the question

[How can I change the default indentation based on filetype?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4/how-can-i-change-the-default-indentation-based-on-filetype)

and its answers.
Some recommend to not use autocmds but to place

```
setlocal indentexpr=
```

into a file such as `~/.vim/after/indent/tex.vim` which is always sourced by vim and has the last word.

Comment: Of note, these can (and should) be set locally. Also, these options won’t persist—adding them to an ftplugin can help this.

Answer (score 0):

Within your `.vimrc` file, add the line

```
autocmd FileType plaintex,tex,context setlocal indentexpr=
```

where

1. `autocmd` automatically applies the setup when criterion is met
2. `FileType` is the criterion to be met (for files of certain type)
3. `plaintex,tex,context` are the common filetypes recognized by vim (see [Vim documentation](https://vim-jp.org/vimdoc-en/filetype.html))
4. `setlocal indentexpr=` sets the required indent to be nothing

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Done! Please feel free to improve if necessary!