# Auto-indent after carriage return after line containing open curly brace

Tags: indentation

I recently upgraded my Cygwin from a 2015 installation (5 years ago) to the current "2020" version.  Gvim now automatically indents by `shiftwidth` columns when I press return after a curly brace `{` on a line by itself.  From an initial web search, I think this might be related to the `cindent` option, so I issued the command `set nocindent`.  The behaviour still persists.  *Can someone suggest what help page to look at next?*

**Background:** I've been using autoindent for years, but that only matches the indentation of a new line to the indentation of the preceding line, which is what I want.  What I'm trying to disable is indentation that is `shiftwidth` more than in the preceding line.  I am using the same `vimrc` file as before the 2020 upgrade of Cygwin.

Here are some key options in my vim session:

```
indentexpr=GetTeXIndent()
tabstop=3
shiftwidth=3
nocindent
nosmartindent
filetype=tex
```

Here is a minimum working example (MWE) file `test.tex` that exhibits my problem:

```
% test.tex
%---------
%        1         2
%234567890123456789012345   <-- Physical character column number
      navigation and direct manipulation of the data.\footnote
      {%
```

I position my cursor on the `{` in column 7 and, in normal mode, press `S` or `C` to enter insert mode (and overwrite the text).  I then enter `{%<CR>`, which creates a new line and positions the insertion point on column 10.

Even as I was typing the preceding paragraph and this paragraph, whenever I press `<CR>` to start a new line following a line containing the `{` character, the insertion point gets indented to column 4 instead of being positioned on column 1.  (Yes, all of this text was composed in the file `test.tex`).  The `:map` command shows that the key `{` is not mapped to anything.

*For those who have tried the MWE, even if you don't know the answer, it would be helpful in identifying the cause of the problem to know whether you get the same behaviour.*

**New info**

The unwanted extra indentation only afflicts a text file if the file name extension is `*.tex`, not if it is `*.txt`.  It seems that I need to delve into how syntax-dependent behaviour controlled by the file type.  I peeked into `/usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/tex.vim`, but I think that deciphering it will be a long-term endeavour.

Comment: What does `:set indentexpr?` say? How about `:set smartindent?`? And finally `:set ft?`? Please edit your question with the answers to these.

Comment: If you're editing a file with source code for any C-like language (C, C++, Java, etc.) then what you describe is, I believe, the default behavior. I don't recall this being something introduced in the last 5 years but I'm not 100% sure. You are using the same vimrc as you did with the previous version? (If  you're not editing source code, just regular text, then that behavior would be strange/incorrect for default config.)

Comment: Thanks, filbranden & B Layer.  I added the requested details into the question.  I am using the same `vimrc` file with the exception of mapping `<C-2>` through `<C-12>` to different font setting commands, since different fonts are installed in the 2020 Cygwin installation of X-windows.

Comment: This seems rather default for latex-indenting to, no?

Comment: @D. Ben Knoble: It wasn't be behaviour before the 2020 upgrade.  In any case, I would like to disable it.  It's causing problems in that a new line is indented even if the `{` in the preceding line is in the middle of the line and in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behavior is being enabled by the [custom indentation function](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/indent/tex.vim#L169) for the `tex` filetype.

You can configure the behavior of that function, by setting some variables in your vimrc.

For your specific case, to disable indentation after braces, you can use:

```
let g:tex_indent_brace = 0
```

The `tex` indentation also indents `\item` elements in a special way, which you can disable with:

```
let g:tex_indent_items = 0
```

---

If you want to **completely block** Vim indentation for filetype `tex`, one good way to do it is to create an `indent/tex.vim` file that supercedes the one you want to block.

You can create a file `~/.vim/indent/tex.vim`, which comes earlier than the one in Vim runtimes in the search path, and add the following contents to it:

```
let b:did_indent = 1
```

This way, when the one you want to block gets to run, it will see that indentation is already configured and so it will skip it.

(That's better than messing with permissions or removing the `indent/tex.vim` in runtimes, since an operating system update will probably revert those changes.)

---

Note that you can't really avoid the indentation function by unsetting `indentexpr` from your vimrc. The indentation plugin will always load when the filetype is determined, which happens much later than your vimrc.

Disabling indentation plugins altogether from your vimrc *will* work, so `filetype plugin off` works as long as nothing else is re-enabling it later on. (Check with a plain `:filetype`, which will tell you which items are enabled.)

It's unclear why you started getting these starting with an upgrade, since that code in `indent/tex.vim` seems to be around for quite a long time... Perhaps you didn't have the Vim runtime files installed and now you do?

Another possibility is that, starting with Vim 8, if you don't have a vimrc file, a default one will be loaded, which will most likely enable all filetype support and have these plug-ins start to load when previously they wouldn't. See [`:help defaults.vim`](https://vimhelp.org/starting.txt.html#defaults.vim) for details on that. In any case, the solution for that one is simple, just create a vimrc file, even if it's an empty one, that will prevent you from getting the settings from the defaults file.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation and solution, filbranden.  Unfortunately, I am unable to replicate my problem. I started a virgin `Gvim` session on `test.tex` -- no extraneous indenting.  I tried started `Gvim` on `test.txt` and then issuing `:e test.tex` -- nada. In both cases, my `vimrc` did not contain `set indentexpr=`. Without the ability to replicate the problem, I can't mark your answer as the answer, but I will certainly upvote it, if I have enough points.  Thanks again.

Comment: @user2153235 Well, if the problem is not happening anymore I guess that's a good sign... Anyways, if it comes back, use the tips in here to troubleshoot it. Or feel free to leave a message here if that happens again!

Comment: For sure, your procedure is going to be a valuable resource when the problem recurs.  I happened on more than one machine, so it's due to something I'm invoking more than on an isolated basis. I thought that the triggering event might even be captured in my `mksession` file, since I routinely use that migrate my work & the state of my `Gvim` session between work & home computers. But sourcing that file still does not reproduce the problem. It's actually quite baffling.

Comment: This is driving me totally bananas.  Now it's starting to extraneously indent after a line containing `\item` by itself.  All I want to do is write a report that requires some really deep thinking, and I'm fighting the vagaries of an dictatorial package.  As soon as I get uncommitted time, I will seek out how to turn off all file-type dependent indentation (but keeping the syntax highlighting heuristics).

Comment: **EUREKA** `chmod a-rwx /usr/share/vim/vim81/indent/tex.vim`....would it be of any value to add that to your answer?

Comment: @user2153235 Haha yeah that should solve it.  It's too big of a hack, so I wouldn't recommend that others do that. It's possible your use of sessions might be what's preserving it even through vimrc configuration changes... But hey if that fixes it for you, for now, that's good for you. If it comes back, try these again. Setting the variable (`g:tex_indent_brace`) should have an immediate effect.

Comment: OK, thanks.  BTW, the extraneous indenting after `\item` did not occur in a session in which the `mksession` file was sourced. I think the hack only works if you start a new session anyway, and time is still needed to tell whether it truly prevents all manner of extraneous indenting....

Comment: @user2153235 Yeah I can reproduce that. You can prevent it with `let g:tex_indent_items = 0`.

Comment: Kay, thanks. Time to consolidate & update ye olde vimrc, which has fragmented across my computers....

Comment: @user2153235 Alright, updated the answer with more... Take a look at the second approach, that's a somewhat more elegant and maintainable way to **block** that indentation configuration file completely... Regarding syncing your machines, consider turning `~/.vim` into a git repository and use `~/.vim/vimrc` as a path to your config (it's a valid path for it in modern versions of Vim, not only `~/.vimrc`). That way you can store *all* your vim config together and use git to sync it on a server (maybe even GitHub?) that you can then sync your machines from.

Comment: Thanks, filbranden.  There are some places and machines from which external connectivity is very limited (not necessarily in terms of bandwidth).  So I'm OK carting around a vimrc, as long as it's the same one.  Probably better than a true single source, so that if it breaks on one location, I can roll back and take my time figuring out the cause.  As for the original indent problem, I used `~/.vim/indent/tex.vim`.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this page](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20560/why-does-vim-still-auto-indent-latex-after-i-set-noai-noci-nosi), I found that `:set indentexpr=` removed `tex` file-dependent extraneous indentation.  I intend to put it in my `vimrc` file.

Just a cautionary note: As *filbranden* said, this solution might not be persistent.  If you are able to get any of his solutions working, it will less of a hack than `:set indentexpr=`.  If for some reason you are running into problems, however, and don't have the time to troubleshoot and experiment, then `:set indentexpr=` might get you going for the immediate present.

To possibly save others time, based on [this page](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/How_to_stop_auto_indenting), I also tried the following without success:

```
filetype indent off
filetype indent plugin off
```

Comment: Setting `indentexpr=` from your vimrc won't work, since that will be overridden by the filetype plugin when it loads later on. Using `filetype indent off` *should* work. But there's a more specific solution to address your issue with braces only... See my answer.