# LaTeX: turn off text wrap and auto indent in maths environments

Tags: indentation, filetype-tex, wrapping, plugin-vim-latex, textwidth

I use vim with vim-latex for editing latex files.  I always have hard wrapping enabled using `set tw=80`.  I also have the default vim-latex auto indent settings enabled.

I wonder if there is a way to disable hard wrapping and any form of automatic indentation when I am in a maths environment?  That is, when I am between `\begin{IEEEeqnarray*}` and `\end{IEEEeqnarray*}`, for example, or any other maths environment.

There is a partial answer here: [Why does vim still auto-indent LaTeX after I set noai noci nosi?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/20560/why-does-vim-still-auto-indent-latex-after-i-set-noai-noci-nosi) It doesn't help with disabling text wrapping though.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Thanks!  I looked into this a bit more, and it seems it may be difficult: https://github.com/preservim/vim-pencil/issues/92.  The autoformat blacklist feature in vim-pencil looks promising, although I haven't got it to work yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following solution is loosely based on inkarkat's [OnSyntaxChange](https://github.com/inkarkat/vim-OnSyntaxChange) and uses the built-in `vimtex` function `vimtex#syntax#in_mathzone` (see [here](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/1880)).  I have the following code in `.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`.  Every time the cursor moves or a buffer is entered, the function checks whether the current syntax zone is a maths zone, and adjusts indentation and text wrapping accordingly.

```
function! SwitchTextWidth()
        if vimtex#syntax#in_mathzone()
                setlocal tw=0 noautoindent nosmartindent nocindent indentexpr&
        else
                setlocal tw=85 autoindent smartindent cindent indentexpr=VimtexIndentExpr()
        endif
endfunction
augroup cursor_moves
        autocmd! * <buffer>
        autocmd CursorMoved  <buffer> call SwitchTextWidth()
        autocmd CursorMovedI <buffer> call SwitchTextWidth()
        autocmd BufEnter     <buffer> call SwitchTextWidth()
augroup END
```

I chose to write my own function, rather than use OnSyntaxChange, so that I could use the built-in vimtex mathzone check.

Comment: The executes at the end are not necessary, and you would do well to wrap that in an augroup (you can then use `autocmd! * <buffer>` to clear the group, same as you would normally with `autocmd!` for a global augroup/autocommand pairing.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Just edited the code to implement them.