# How to set statusline for specific buffer

Tags: vimscript, buffers, netrw, statusline

I want to use netrwm instead of nerdtree. I have my own statusline but I don't want it to be displayed in netrw. Nerdtree had it's own option for it (`let NERDTreeStatusline=""`) which made it really simple.

I know that I can set statusline based on buffers but I'm total noob at Vim script and I don't know how to detect the right buffer, etc, etc. So if there is some one willing to help, please and thank you!

Comment: I'm almost positive there are answers on this site describing how to get that information.

Comment: @BLayer netrw doesn't show up in `:buffers` or `:ls a` for me. which is the main problem I could probably come up with something if I knew which buffer it is

Comment: @user419050 the filetype for a netrw buffer is `netrw`. With that information, you can just use an `ftplugin`, as described in this answer: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/4/how-can-i-change-the-default-indentation-based-on-filetype.

Comment: It doesn't show up because it's an "unlisted" buffer. You can see those with `:ls!` or `:ls u`. All you'll see there is the same thing you see as the buffer name in other places...something like "NetrwTreeListing". Use this site's search function...there are a ton of answers for "netrw" + "buffer". You're sure to find something helpful amongst them.